# Detecting when user has scrolled to the pixel just before seeing the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect when my user has scrolled to the point just before he sees the first pixel of the footer.

Here is how I'm trying to calculate the position just before the footer:

```
footerVisible = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $('footer').height() - 1;
alert(footerVisible);
```

I'm taking the height of the whole document and subtracting the viewport height and the height of the footer.

This alerts me `3695`.

Now I'm logging the scroll position like this:

```
$window.scroll(function(e){
    console.log($window.scrollTop());
}
```

When scrolling all the way to the bottom of the document (ie: seeing the full footer and end of document) the console indicates I'm at position `3211`.

My logic is clearly flawed somewhere...

**How can I calculate the 'scrollTop' position that the user will be on just before he sees the first pixel of the footer. 
Can anyone provide a fiddle that throws an alert juste before the user sees the footer?**

**EDIT**
Fiddle available   [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zvnVL/1/)

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle of what you have so someone can properly expound?

Comment: @Seth I've uploaded a fiddle! Also whoever down-voted, I would love an explanation as to why this isn't a question about programming according to the rules defined in the help center? With an explanation I could hopefully improve the question to try to get an answer to a question that hasn't been asked here before and that can perhaps also be useful to others in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the "first pixel of the footer", the scroll position will have to be one pixel less from one window height from the height of the footer.

```
var footerVisible = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $('footer').height() - 1;
```

Your scroll function should be something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() >= footerVisible ) {
        alert('Footer Visible');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes but that isn't really my problem here, `footerVisible` is `3695` in my browser when I calculate it like that ('adding' your -1 that I forgot), yet when I scroll all the way to the bottom I'm only at `3211`. I believe that that can't be the way to calculate the point where the footer will appear.

Comment: I've uploaded a fiddle up there!